# How to split single quoted comma delimited values containing commas in Ruby

Tags: ruby, split, csv

Say I have a string with comma delimited values enclosed in single quotes that may or may not include commas, like this:

```
"'apples,bananas','lemons'"
```

and I want to split that into an array

```
["apples,bananas", "lemons"]
```

Apparently, if I `split(',')` the string I get

```
[ "'apples", "bananas'", "lemons" ]
```

which I don't understand. The only way to do this that I've come up with is

```
a = []
s = "'apples,bananas','lemons'"
s.scan(/\'([^\']+)\'/){|i| a << i[0]}

# result is ["apples,bananas", "lemons"]
```

But is there a more elegant way? Is there something with the split method that I don't get, which is causing the strange result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually split is working the way it's supposed to. But it seems like you're trying to split comma separated values. And there's already a solution for it in Ruby's stdlib:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html

Or if you want an external libray (that supposed to be better, faster, ...) use [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: The CSV lib seems helpful. If the string would be formatted as s = "\"apples,bananas\", lemons" (using escaped double quotes instead of single quotes) I could do CSV::parse_line(s) and get the desired result. This might be a possible solution.

Comment: At least with FasterCSV, you can parse the existing string without reformatting. require 'fastercsv'; "'apples,bananas','lemons'".parse_csv(:quote_char => "'") yields ["apples,bananas", "lemons"], which is what you're looking for, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The result of #split is perfectly normal, the method isn't supposed to tokenize the string in any way. Pick the way you know that works over an elegant one.